# Как получать props при первой отрисовке

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть контейнерная компонента в которой я получаю айди и закидываю этот айди в функцию и идет запрос, по идее должны придти пропсы сразу,но они undefined.
Но при повторном входе в эту же компоненту нужные пропсы показываются.

Объясните как сделать чтобы при первом же рендере показывались пропсы?

```js
class View extends React.Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    //беру айди из пропсов
    let id = this.props.match.params.id;
    //отправляю его в стейт
    this.props.GetProjData(id);
  }

  render() {
    return <ProjView {...this.props}></ProjView>;
  }
}

let mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      NameProj: state.project.OneProject.NameProj,
      Text: state.project.OneProject.Text,
      target: state.project.OneProject.target,
      startdate: state.project.OneProject.startdate,
      enddate: state.project.OneProject.enddate
    },
    error: state.settings.error,
    loading: state.settings.loading
  };
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Переходите с классов на хуки, они гораздо удобнее:

```
function View (props) {
  useEffect(() {
    let id = props.match.params.id;
    props.GetProjData(id);
  }, [props.match.params.id])

  render() {
    return <ProjView {...props}></ProjView>;
  }
}
```